# What can cause JomSocial Event creation to trigger a hacker alert?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jomsocial

Besides the obvious "because they're a hacker" of course.

I have a client using Joomla with JomSocial and they allow their community members to create their own events. They have just updated to Joomla 3.8 and now have folks getting an alert when they try to create an event.

We have tested this with our admin accounts and our testing, non-admin accounts with no issues.

I'm trying to get a screenshot of the error message. In the meantime, any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Unless we know what the alert says, it's very hard to give any insight.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a setting in the Joomla firewall and it was working as expected. Apparently, this particular "trusted" user accidentally put some "<" and ">" characters in his description which triggered a code injection protocol.

The Joomla admin was able to clear this user's IP from the blocked list and now they can add events again.

Hopefully, this will help someone in the future.

Comment: Ah yes, we have a similar issue with our extension which derives from not beig able to post a message such as `<3` if you use `JInputFilter`. I tried fixing this on the Joomla repo but it caused hundred of errors so I think I'll leave it to a PHP dev to fix :)